# SublimeLinter not obeying "pep8_ignore" settings

Tags: python, sublimetext2

I am using Sublime Linter and cannot get PEP 8 (W191) to go away with the following settings. 
Why?

```
{
    "color_scheme": "Packages/Color Scheme - Default/Mac Classic.tmTheme",
    "fold_buttons": false,
    "font_face": "SourceCodePro-Regular",
    "font_size": 13.0,
    "ignored_packages":
    [
        "Vintage"
    ],
    "line_padding_bottom": 1,
    "line_padding_top": 1,
    "word_wrap": true,
    "pep8": false,
    "pep8_ignore": 
    [
        "W191"
    ]
}
```

Comment: From what I remember, `pep8_ignore` should have a comma-separated string of ignored PEPs, not an array, as the value.

Comment: Hmm. Tried removing the array brackets and I still get the error. Also, I doubt it would have a comma-separated string without the array brackets because that would be invalid JSON.

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking of AutoPEP8.

Comment: With E503 (line too long), my observation is that it's only ignored when opening an existing file. It is **not** ignored in newly created files, I have to close and re-open it to get long lines ignored.

Comment: @lenz, I had the same issue with E503 not being ignored, and it was solved by restarting ST2. Though it was a newly created file, so I'm not sure what the problem was

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try setting `Packages/User/SublimeLinter.sublime-settings` to the following:

```json
{
    "pep8": false,
    "pep8_ignore": 
    [
        "W191"
    ]
}
```

and see if that fixes things. SublimeLinter may not be looking in your regular user settings file for these options.

Comment: -1. Setting `pep8` to off turns off pep8 checking completely, which is not what you are looking for, right?

Comment: @jmagnusson If you'd bothered to fully read the OP's settings, he already had `"pep8": false`. He accepted the answer, so apparently it **was** what he was looking for...